# UIPanGesture working side to side not up and down in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I am building a game with cards in a 7 x 7 grid and 3 x 7 side grids (north east south and west of 7 x 7.
I want to use the pangesture to scroll in the cards that are to the side but right now the addition of cards on the right side causes the pangesture to work on both sides but not top or bottom. The line "arrayAllCards.append(button)" makes it not work for north and south.

`

```
for j in 0...6{
            for i in 0...3 {
                let image = UIImage(named: arrayShuffle[(i+1)*(j+1)].suitRank) as UIImage?
                var cardPos: [Int] = []
                cardPos.append(j)
                cardPos.append(7+i)
                
                var button = Card(suitRank: arrayShuffle[(i+1)*(j+1)].suitRank,
                                  position: cardPos,
                                  suit: arrayShuffle[(i+1)*(j+1)].suit,
                                  rank: arrayShuffle[(i+1)*(j+1)].rank,
                                  x: cardPos[0] * (Int(screensize)/7),
                                  y: cardPos[1] * (Int(screensize)/7),
                                  isChosen: false)
                
                arrayShuffle.remove(at: (i+1)*(j+1))
                
                
                
                let valueX = Int(CGFloat(0 + (i * sizeButton)))
                let valueY = Int(CGFloat(middlepos - CGFloat(sizeButton * j)))
                
                button.frame = CGRect(x: valueX,
                                      y: valueY,
                                      width: sizeButton,
                                      height: sizeButton)
                button.backgroundColor = .red
                button.configuration?.imagePadding = 0
                button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
                button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
                
        
               arrayAllCards.append(button)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
                let scrollGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeUp))
                button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                view.addSubview(button)
                view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollGesture)
                
              
            
//
//                l
               
            }
        }

//Here is the UIPangesture code 

@objc func swipeUp(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            
        
        var vertical: Bool = false
        let moveDirection = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        if (abs(moveDirection.x) < abs(moveDirection.y)){
            vertical = true
        }
        let result = UIPanGestureRecognizer.State.ended.rawValue
       
        
        var screenRealEstate: Int = (Int) (self.screenheight - self.screensize) / 2
        screenRealEstate -= (Int)(screensize) / 7 * 2
        
        //var stop: Int = (Int)(screensize) / 7 * 3
        var stoppage: Bool = false
        for i in arrayAllCards {
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
            //
            //                let value1 : Int = Int(arrayAllCards[6].center.y)
            //                let value: Int = self.origin -  3 * self.buttonSize
            //                
            let value1 : Int = Int(arrayAllCards[90].center.y)
            let value: Int = (self.origin + 7 * buttonSize) -  3 * self.buttonSize
            let value2: Int = (self.origin + 13 * buttonSize)
            
            let value3 : Int = Int(arrayAllCards[90].center.x)
            let value4 : Int = 4 * self.buttonSize
            
            let value5 : Int = 10 * self.buttonSize
            
            if(value3 > value4 && value3 < value5 && !vertical){
                i.center.x = translation.x/10 + i.center.x
                
            }
            
            if(value1 > value && value1 < value2 && vertical){
                i.center.y = translation.y/10 + i.center.y // Customize this.
                
            }
            if(gesture.state.rawValue == 3){
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    for k in 0..<self.arrayAllCards.count
                    {
                        self.arrayAllCards[k].center.x = CGFloat(self.arrayAllCards[k].position[1]) * CGFloat(self.buttonSize) + CGFloat(self.buttonSize/2)
                        
                        self.arrayAllCards[k].center.y = CGFloat((Int)(self.origin)) + CGFloat(self.arrayAllCards[k].position[0] * self.buttonSize) + CGFloat(self.buttonSize/2)
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                }, completion: { finished in
                }
                )}
            
            
        }
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lay with the array size in the pan gesture.

```
let value1 : Int = Int(arrayAllCards[133].center.y)
```

was needed instead of `arrayAllCards[90]`. I was not accounting for the extra created cards.